# Android Gradle Flavor values dependent on other flavor dimensions

Tags: android, gradle

So I've been working on a bit of a white label style project for a while, and I've run into a bit of an issue with extensibility.  Specifically, the way the project works, I need to be able to support multiple backend environments, each with unique credentials, on a per-client basis.

I've baked this behavior into the gradle using two flavor dimensions, one for the client and one for the backend, but I'm having a bit of trouble in getting them to gel together as seamlessly as I'd like.

Here's an example of the gradle setup:

```
productFlavors {
        client1 {
            applicationId "com.app.client1"
            dimension "customer"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Client 1"
        }
        client2{
            applicationId "com.app.client2"
            dimension "customer"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Client 2"
        }

        dev {
            ext {
                packageExtension = ".DEV"
            }
            dimension "environment"
            resValue "string", "url", "https://dev.hostname.com/"
        }
        uat {
            ext {
                packageExtension = ".UAT"
            }
            dimension "environment"
            resValue "string", "url", "https://uat.hostname.com/"
        }
        stage {
            ext {
                packageExtension = ".STAGE"
            }
            dimension "environment"
            resValue "string", "url", "https://stg.hostname.com/"
        }
        prod {
            ext {
                packageExtension = ""
            }
            dimension "environment"
            resValue "string", "url", "https://hostname.com/"
        }
    }
```

This works great for granting access to the right environment and unique code for each client, but it means that I can't include the client ID in the gradle.  I have to stick it in a resource file out in the client1Dev directory and the like in order to get the right value at run time.

My question is, is there a way to move the client ID into gradle and get the right value based on the combination of customer and environment flavors?

For example, what I would like to do is something like:

```
        client1 {
            applicationId "com.app.client1"
            dimension "customer"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Client 1"
            dev{
                resValue "string", "clientId", "1032145d8eefa00aff0098b08c9d"
            }
            uat{
                resValue "string", "clientId", "8654684561584798531985964/56"
            }
        }
        client2{
            applicationId "com.app.client2"
            dimension "customer"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Client 2"
            dev{
                resValue "string", "clientId", "89612ad8967a00aff0098b08c08e"
            }
            uat{
                resValue "string", "clientId", "8612ad890981237409d0ab08c08f"
            }
        }
```

Something along these lines that would allow me to store my client ID in the gradle file along with the other backend setup info.  I can't find anything about this kind of thing though, and I'm hoping someone on here can shed some light on how to do it, or at least tell me it's impossible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use separate source trees for the multi-flavor combination and store the Strings directly in the correct resource (since that's essentially what `resValue "string" "{ID}" "{VALUE}"` is doing anyway).

```
src/
  main/
    java/
    res/
      values/
        strings_ids.xml
          <string name="clientId">override_me</string>
  client1Dev/
  client1Uat/
  client2Dev/
    res/
      values/
        strings_ids.xml
          <string name="clientId">89612ad8967a00aff0098b08c08e</string>
  client2Uat/
    res/
      values/
        strings_ids.xml
          <string name="clientId">8612ad890981237409d0ab08c08f</string>
```

Or, if you really want to keep in inside the build.gradle file, you could script it with something (less elegant) along the lines of:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  if (variant.getFlavorName().equalsIgnoreCase("client1Dev")) {
    variant.resValue "string", "clientId", "1032145d8eefa00aff0098b08c9d"
  }
  else if (variant.getFlavorName().equalsIgnoreCase("client1Uat")) {
    variant.resValue "string", "clientId", "8654684561584798531985964/56"
  }
}
```

But you can see the latter will get nasty, pretty quickly

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently doing your first suggestion and referencing a resource that gets overridden directly in the project structure.  I was just hoping I could slot it directly into the gradle file instead so that everything that needed to change between clients was in a single, easy to access file.  From what I've found, it didn't seem likely to be something I could do cleanly, but I figured it was worth asking in case it was just my google-fu not being up to par.

Seems like you've confirmed it for me though, so cheers!